# Python: Looping through a dataset

Tags: python, arrays, object, for-loop

I've managed to make a function that loops though all the objects in my dataset which i specify as an argument when i call the function. Now this function returns an array of 8 objects.

Here's the function..

```
def oneDimRepeat(colName, len):
    cols = []
    for x in range(1,len+1):
        tempHead = colName + "[" + str(x) + "]"
        cols.append(tempHead)
    return cols
```

So i call this function as..

```
oneDimRepeat("columnName", 8)
```

And this is what it returns..

```
['columnName[1]','columnName[2]','columnName[3]','columnName[4]','columnName[5]', 
'columnName[6]','columnName[7]','columnName[8]']
```

Which i thought is perfect, but when i try to call any of these objects for plotting, i get an error message.

Can anyone help me with this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. You just have a list of strings.

Comment: It looks like you might be new to the site! Are you using any packages outside the default python? Do you have something like pandas? Are you reading this data from a csv file? Are the objects from a runtime application or are they being read elsewhere? Some more clarification might help

Comment: What are you plotting? Is this list your x value or a labels? and what are you plotting it against?

Comment: I imported pandas to read the dataset from a csv file. And I don't know if it's in a runtime phase or not, but i assume it is since i can't plot the objects.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is, that i want to avoid having to define each array of objects by hand. This works though for plotting a bar chart (as the x value) but it's very time consuming, as i have over 4000 objects to define (= column names). 
And i'm plotting it against a numpy array of 8 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in how to use a function in a function. I've made a function for plotting a bar chart, and i wanted to add this function i just mentioned with the oneDimRepeat function.

The right way to do that is..

```
x = np.arange(8)
barPlot(x, df[("columnName1", 8)])
```

This makes the barPlot that i wanted.